# Method for comparing URLs with the same root

Tags: c#, .net, url, uri

I am looking into trying to compare 2 URLs in C# for equal root domains, I.E.

`sub.example.com` matches `example.com` and `othersub.example.com`.

I had a look into [using the Uri class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0), but that will parse the full URL including the subdomains.

I had thought about splitting the string at each `.` and then comparing the last 2 last elements which would normally be the root domain name, however that causes issues as often the TLD can also have a subdomain I.E. `example.com.au` would then match `other.com.au`.

I guess I'm hoping if anyone knows a NuGet library that can take into account common top level domains (including multi part ones) and then compare the actual specified domain

Comment: Library recommendations are categorically off-topic for this site. You'd essentially want a list of all possible TLDs and "sub" TLDs, and then find the longest one that matches. Once you have that, you know which part is the "domain name", so you'll be able to determine the subdomain of that registered domain.

Comment: Subdomains are defined as using a `.` so splitting on `.` should be fine. What you are worried about is essentially not possible in C# without outside help, you would need https://publicsuffix.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `Nager.PublicSuffix` package.

Install via nuget:

```
PM> Install-Package Nager.PublicSuffix
```

Example:

```
var domainParser = new DomainParser(new WebTldRuleProvider());

var domainInfo = domainParser.Parse("sub.test.co.uk");
//domainInfo.Domain = "test";
//domainInfo.Hostname = "sub.test.co.uk";
//domainInfo.RegistrableDomain = "test.co.uk";
//domainInfo.SubDomain = "sub";
//domainInfo.TLD = "co.uk";
```

Then compare via the `domainInfo.TLD`